# 'System.Guid' is not an attribute class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, class-attributes

I am creating a new dll application with Visual Studio 2013 based on .net 4.5.
When trying to define the `Guid` attribute on my class like this:

```
[Guid("4245366B-0484-4A41-A2E8-C7D9FC3A4ED7")]
```

The compiler gives me the error

> 'System.Guid' is not an attribute class.

Any idea what's missing?

Comment: the problem is clearly stated in the error message. `"System.Guid' is not an attribute class."` you are looking for [GuidAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include the correct namespace or `using` statement. If you don't do that, it will match [`System.Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (instead of [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the `Attribute` part is stripped out for our convenience), which indeed isn't an attribute. It's a little confusing, but true...

This code will get you there:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("4245366B-0484-4A41-A2E8-C7D9FC3A4ED7")]
```

Answer (score 5):

You must add reference to the `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

or state the full name for the class:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("4245366B-0484-4A41-A2E8-C7D9FC3A4ED7")]
```

or use class name with postfix `Attribute`:

```
[GuidAttribute("4245366B-0484-4A41-A2E8-C7D9FC3A4ED7")]
```

or use full class name with postfix `Attribute`:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute("4245366B-0484-4A41-A2E8-C7D9FC3A4ED7")]
```

You can find more information on [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx)